# Airflow on conda - folder structure

Tags: unix, anaconda, conda, airflow

I have bare bones airflow installation on conda - I managed to create custom operators by putting them in path:

```sh
airflow/dags/operators/custom_operator.py
```

then calling from dag as:

```sh
from operators.custom_operator import CustomOperator
```

how can I instead achieve folder structure:

```sh
airflow/operators/custom_operator.py
```

Which would be called from dag as:

```sh
from airflow.operators.custom_operator import CustomOperator
```

*In case if you think that's a bad approach - please point it out in your answer/comment* happy to tweak my approach, if there are better design patterns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly - the solution here is in `airflow.cfg` (your airflow config file) to move parameter `dags_folder` one directory up - to `$AIRFLOW_HOME`, so instead of having:

```sh
....
[core]
dags_folder = /home/user/airflow/dags
....
```

Just make it:

```sh
....
[core]
dags_folder = /home/user/airflow
....
```

Airflow apparently will look recursivelly for dags, and capture only classes defined as dags... Whereas you can then keep clean folder structure, with custom operators, utility functions, custom sensors etc. outside `dags/` folder.